# Queries in RPostgreSQL are very slow

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny, rpostgresql

Currently I'm building a Shiny APP using several queries to a PostgreSQL database (mainly SELECT and INSERT statements). The application works but I'm trying to make it faster. When I compare the execution times between the same query using the RPostgreSQL package and a db client like Postico, it's taking 8 times more with the RPostgreSQL package.

Any ideas of ways of boosting the performance or connecting to a PostgreSQL database from R?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure there's really enough information here to troubleshoot it for you. There could be a lot of differences in your data pipeline. Do you have a reproducible example? Have you tried other R libraries like `odbc`? You can use it with a postgres driver and it should be much faster (at least it's much faster than `RODBC`).

Comment: Can you provide something reproducible?  Say a shell script calling `psql` to create a table, insert some date and then some timed operations comparing RPostgreSQL (which uses the same C library as other Postgres frontends...) to Postico etc?

Comment: You could give a try to [RPostgres](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RPostgres).

Comment: thanks @Scarabee, the RPostgres package is at least 50% faster than the RPostgreSQL. On the other hand, we also developed a external python API for making the queries and returning them to R, I will update this thread when we have results

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever heard about the package **`dbplyr`** (with the **b**)?

I would recommend it because this package enables your **`dplyr`** (with no **b**) to be used with SQL databases.

There are many advantages since the way you interact with your databases will shift

**from this:**

[image]

**to this:**

[image]

These images are extracted from a great article entitled **"Databases using R"** by Edgar Ruiz (2017). You should take a look at it [HERE](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/05/17/databases-using-r/) for more details.

The main advantages presented by Mr. Ruiz are, and I quote:

"
  *1) Run data exploration over all of the data - Instead of coming up with a plan to decide what data to import, we can focus on analyzing the data inside the database, which in turn should yield faster insights.*

*2) Use the SQL Engine to run the data transformations - We are, in effect, pushing the computation to the database because dplyr is sending SQL queries to the database.*

*3) Collect a targeted dataset - After become familiar with the data and choosing the data points that will either be shared or modeled, a final query can then be used to bring back only that data into memory in R.*

*4) All your code is in R! - Because we are using dplyr to communicate with the database, there is no need to change language, or tools, to perform the data exploration.* "

So, you will probably gain the speed you are looking for with **`dbplyr`/`dplyr`**.

You should give it a try.

You can find more information about it and how to establish the connection with your PostgreSQL Server using the **DBI** package at:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbplyr/vignettes/dbplyr.html

and

https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/05/17/databases-using-r/

Comment: This answer has very little to do with the question, besided also mentioning R and Postgres.  As I read OP's question, he was not asking for dbplyr commercial.

Comment: @Dirk Well, I'm not receiving any $$$ from Edgar Ruiz lol. The OP is asking for "ideas of ways of boosting the performance". Why do you think dbplyr would not be an alternative for this?